# Illegal characters in path. while bundles javascript files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I am trying to bundlesup my javascrip files and css files to My MVC project. It is throwing exception while adding them.

```
Illegal characters in path. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.

Source Error: 



Line 9:          public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
Line 10:         {
Line 11:             bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
Line 12:             "~/js/bootstrap.js",
Line 13:            "~/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js",
                    "~/js/jquery.isotope.js",
                    "~/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.0",
                    "~/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js",
                    "~/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js",
                    "~/js/revolution.custom.js",
                    "~/js/custom.js"
                    ));


Stack Trace: 



[ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.]
   System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional) +10631190
   System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.CheckIllegalCharacters(String[] str) +30
   System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList) +97
   System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String path) +63
   System.Web.InternalSecurityPermissions.PathDiscovery(String path) +29
   System.Web.HttpRequest.MapPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, VirtualPath baseVirtualDir, Boolean allowCrossAppMapping) +149
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.MapPath(String path) +104
   System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.<get_MapPathMethod>b__0(String virtualPath) +67
   System.Web.Optimization.ItemRegistry.Include(String[] virtualPaths) +644
   System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.Include(String[] virtualPaths) +64
   IntensifyTech.IntensifyTechConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) in c:\Users\sxxx\SkyDrive\Trunk\IntensifyTech\IntensifyTech\App_Start\IntensifyTechConfig.cs:11
   IntensifyTech.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in c:\Users\sxxxx\SkyDrive\Trunk\IntensifyTech\IntensifyTech\Global.asax.cs:24

[HttpException (0x80004005): Illegal characters in path.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +9859725
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): Illegal characters in path.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9873912
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

Comment: Try commenting out the files one by one and see path to which file is causing the issue. Sometimes when you copy paste the urls it happens.

Comment: My guess would be the fancybox line.  You're including a query string -- which is part of a URL.  The bundles only accept virtual paths, not URLs.  But try @PSCoder's suggestion to verify.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, its definitely this item: "~/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.0".  This is a virtual path, not a url, so '?' characters are illegal in this context.